# Moving elements in dictionary python to another index

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

If i have a dictionary like this for example:

```
dicta={1:['a','a','a'],2:['b,'b','b'],'N':['n','n','n'],3:['c','c','c']}
```

and i want the N to be in the last position as i convert this dict later on into a df. Is there a way to shift it down?

Finding the index of the N is fine: `index=list(dicta.keys()).index('N')`

but then how would you do the (in pseudo code) `dicta.position[-1] = dicta[index]` bit?

Comment: What version of Python are you on? Dictionaries are only ordered starting with Python 3.7 (with CPython 3.6 already "accidentally" providing it).

Comment: Even in 3.7, dicitonaries don't really provide any tools to change their internal order.  You'd be better off reordering the dataframe after you create it.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh cheers man, ill i give that a go

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using **CPython 3.6+**, since dict are insertion-based ordered, you can move an item to the end by [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop)ping it and then re-assigning it to the dictionary.

```
>>> dicta = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 'N': 'n', 3: 'c'}
>>> dicta['N'] = dicta.pop('N')
>>> dicta
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 'N': 'n'}
```

If you're using lower versions then you're outta luck!

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done with the [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and its method [`OrderedDict.move_to_end()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.move_to_end) with keyword argument `last` set to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

When the order of the dictionaty cannot be relied on (Python <3.7) you also should make sure the numbers are sorted.  You could take the keys, remove the `'N'`, sort the remaining keys, and append the `'N'` afterwards.  Then use this list as explicit `column` argument to the `DataFrame`:

```
In [16]: dicta = {1:['a','a','a'], 2:['b','b','b'],
    ...:          'N': ['n','n','n'], 3:['c','c','c']}

In [17]: columns = list(dicta.keys())

In [18]: columns.remove('N')

In [19]: columns.sort()

In [20]: columns.append('N')

In [21]: pd.DataFrame(dicta, columns=columns)
Out[21]: 
   1  2  3  N
0  a  b  c  n
1  a  b  c  n
2  a  b  c  n
```